# .to_xml with ruby 1.8.7 (ree) and rails 3.1.3 throwing error?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, xml-parsing

So I am trying to implement nice meta-data concept in my application. Basically, I store some details in XML format in a single column in the database but in my application I can access them through a Hash.

```
def extra_info=(data)
    data = {} unless data.is_a?(Hash)
    self[:extra_info] = data.to_xml(:dasherize => false)
end

def extra_info
   Hash.from_xml(self[:extra_info])['hash']
end
```

Rather simple, following what I read on a blog post on the subject.

However, now my application throws an error:

```
ERROR ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
.../app/models/users/usage.rb:35:in to_xml
```

So I tried this

```
def extra_info=(data)
    data = {} unless data.is_a?(Hash)
    self[:extra_info] = data.to_xml
end
```

And still I get the same error! Anyone faced this issue? What's wrong?

Comment: Can you post what `data.inspect` shows you?

Comment: @ScottJShea: Nothing at all! This is in my model file, so I can't start the app or the console or anything!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a backward compatibility issue with the version of builder included in Rails. Problem with REE only.

From elisehuard on github:

> in Ruby 1.8.7 arity of method to_xs is 0 - in 1.9.2 it takes encoding

Criminal. Anyway, much thanks to her for the fix, which can be found [here](https://github.com/elisehuard/builder/commit/53582a84556102b4d81f144f8c6a28cf9157516d).

Answer (score 0):

You should use *read_attribute* and *write_attribute*

Example:

```
def ip 
  # ip is stored as a number, convert the number to a human readable IP address (i.e. 192.168.1.1)
 IPAddr.new(read_attribute(:ip) , Socket::AF_INET).to_s    
end

def ip=(val)
   # ip is stored as a number, convert a human readable ip (i.e. 192.168.1.1) to a number
   write_attribute(:ip, IPAddr.new(val).to_i)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, while that may be an alternative, I still do not know why this is not working!!

Comment: use read and write attributes. did you try it? you can not refer to the self[:extra_info] within the same method definitions. either change the name of your method  or use read/write.